# Navigation Bar Back Button Pop View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When hitting the Back button on a navigation controller, does the view get popped off the stack? If so, how can I test that or make sure that it does it correctly (in other words, created a proper navigation controller)?

I need to see if the view is actually getting popped. Is there anything I can `NSLog` that shows me the stack or something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewController is getting popped from the stack yes. You can also `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);` in `- (void)viewWillAppear` and `- (void)viewDidAppear` methods of the parent viewController to see the differences if you don't trust that Apple engineers did a good job with it.

Comment: Haha its not about the Apple engineers. There is a view when I move into it, it works. When I hit Back and hit a button to move to it again I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error and the app crashes so I am trying to figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Maybe you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS because the variable that you call has already been released, can you post the snippet where you call the push?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the view is popped from the stack. You can check the size of the stack (number of views) to confirm this.

Comment: The view doesn't get unloaded and reloaded again once you go back to it, true?

Comment: It should not be unloaded unless memory gets tight, in which case it may be unloaded.

Comment: But it does get reloaded each time, as in the `viewDidLoad` will get invoked each time its accessed again (or pushed into the stack)?

Comment: Yes, if it has benn unloaded then when it is pushed again viewDidUnload will be called.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);` would give the viewcontrollers array in navigation stack.you can nslog them before the view disappears and after the other view appears